# Predict binary outcome with R

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I have a table includes the following data:

```
Status     | Age | Tenure | Function | Gender | Race | Grade Level
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Active     |  34 |    1.2 | PSO      | Female | White| 26
Terminated |  24 |    0.2 | Finance  | Male   | Asian| 32
Active     |  50 |    4.0 | HR       | Female | Black| 28
Terminated |  23 |    2.9 | Sales    | Male   | Hispa| 20
:
:
:
```

I want find out how are the different variables have impact on the binary outcome - Status, and possibly create a predictive modeling to predict the outcome of Status based on the other variables.

Where do I start? I am thinking of doing a factor analysis to find the P-value for each factor. Is that a right path?

Answer (score 10):

The most obvious thing that comes in mind would be binary response models. In your case I would probably recommend applying logistic regression. It can be done using `glm` function (for Generalized Linear Models) in R. In this case

```
glm(formula = Status ~ Age + Tenure + Function + Gender + Race + Grade Level , 
    family = binomial(logit), data = yourdata)
```

Comment: I used this statement `glm(formula = status ~ age + sex + race + function + grade + tenure, family = binomial(logit), data = data)`, it is giving me an error msg: Error: unexpected '+' in "glm(formula = status ~ age + sex + race + function +". What did I do wrong? :(

Comment: Problem is that column Function corresponds to one of R language keywords and it thinks that you want to start writing function. Simplest solution to rename that column. You can retrieve your column name vector `aux<-colnames(yourdata)` then change the appropriate value in `aux[4]="func"` and then update column names by  `colnames(yourdata)<-aux` .

Comment: I would just add that using `link=logit` is not the only option, the other two commonly used ones being `probit` and `cloglog`. For a discussion on how to choose the link function and in general on binomail models you may also want to have a look at chapter 2 of "Extending the linear model with R" by Julian Faraway.

Comment: @user974514 - thanks, I changed the col header to func based on the method you provided and it worked :)

Comment: this maybe a stupid question, but does the target variable, in my case Status need to be numbers, i.e. 0 and 1 rather than 'Active' vs. 'Terminated'?

Comment: R treats them as factor, i.e. if you transform it to numeric you would probably get 1's and 2's..

Answer (score 1):

This is a logistic regression question. You can fit a model like
`fit <- (status ~ age + tenure + function...)`. This can be done with a variety of techniques, I recommend the package `rms`. You may also want to review Frank Harrell's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441929185). You can validate, calibrate, plot, derive a formula, etc using the functions in the package.